# Access DataContext of Page from MainWindow (with Telerik)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, datacontext

I am relatively new to WPF and I have stumbled across a problem that I just can't seem to find a solution for.

I am sure that there is already a thread concerning a problem like that but in regard of my lacking knowledge it is very likely that I haven't found it or simply did not understand it.

**My problem:**

I am developing a WPF-application in C#. It's an Outlook-Styled application with a big MainWindow with a huge ViewModel and XAML.
What I was trying to do, is to split up the single codefiles a bit to make it a little bit more modular and compact. 
I am using Telerik Controls and tried to outsource the content of single SplitContainers into Pages, which worked fine until now.

Today, a new situation came up which is somehow stupid and wasn't looking too complicated, but somehow I can't get it to work.

**Situation:**

I have a Treeview in my "MainWindow" and whenever I change the selection in there, I want to change a property on my Page that I have made a binding to.

So, when I click on an item in "TreeView_3" I want to set a property via EventHandler (SelectionChanged_TreeView3) on the DataContext of "Page_X".

If I had to do this on the MainWindow, I would typically do it like that:

```
UserViewModel uvm = mainGrid.DataContext as UserViewModel;
```

Then just call whatever property of specific UserViewModel (ViewModel of the MainWindow) I want to access.

I can't do this the same the same way for the page obviously since "mainGrid.DataContext" will always refer to the MainWindow, since this is where the eventhandler is called.

So what I need would be a little explanation on how to access the DataContext from a page with a different ViewModel.

If you need any code in order to explain, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate your concerns. In your code behind your should have only code that handles **view** related stuff. Most often my codebehind is empty.

In your ViewModels you should handle your **data** related logic. So instead of casting the datacontext in your code behind, handle a click with a `Command`in your viewmodel.

Since there is no possibility to bind a command to the `SelectedItemChanged` of your `TreeView` you can use an interaction trigger.

```
<TreeView xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruven it is hard to say without some example code. But it could be that you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the ViewModels?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification

By calling OnPropertyChanged("PropertyName"); in the setter of a viewmodel property the ui will pick up the change.

Also make sure both views are referencing the same object and not copies of the same object.